# wxPython how to put a text in TextCtrl with a button inserted by "Add" Button

Tags: python, button, wxpython

I'm using wxPython to build some GUI... Indeed it isn't an easy program...
Many many user inputs and outputs to be generated...

One part of the program I put an "Add" button that will dynamically add a TextCtrl field and an "Open" button to open a file. After clicking in the "Open" the user can select a file, the file pathway is therefore showed in the TextCtrl field.

Indeed, using a simple example (one TextCtrl one button) I can handle it...
But in a dynamically way, putting several TextCtrl and several Buttons I don't know how to handle it...

In the following code (only a small part of all, some stuff should not be there), I put a "def OpenReadFile" as you can see there after "Open" button click, it will put the text in the last TextCtrl not in the corresponding field... Any ideas?

In another words... Imagine this:
Add (the user can Add "n" samples)

```
"TEXT-1" 'BUTTON-1'
"TEXT-2" 'BUTTON-2'
"TEXT-3" 'BUTTON-3'
```

if the user click in button-3 for example it will put the text in Text-3 field (as expected)
if the user click in button-2, it will put the text in Text-3...

My code so far (Indeed I know where the mistake is, I just don't know what to d0) =[

```
self.addButton = wx.Button(self, label="Add Sample")
self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnAddWidget, self.addButton)
def OnAddWidget(self, event):
    self.samplenumber += 1
    self.sampleTextCtrl = wx.TextCtrl(self, wx.NewId(), "", size = (200,-1))
    self.buttonF = wx.Button(self, buttonId, label = "Select File") #Add Open File Button
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OpenReadFile, self.buttonF) #Add click event
    self.fgs4.Add(self.buttonF, proportion = 1, flag = wx.CENTER, border = -1)
def OpenReadFile(self,event):
    dlg = wx.FileDialog(self, "Open File",
                os.getcwd(), style = wx.OPEN)

    if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
        self.filename = dlg.GetPath()
        self.sampleTextCtrl.SetValue(self.filename)
```

I'm pretty sure that I do have to do some stuff in OpenReadFile =]

**EDITED**

I've put a dict before, got the button ID and the TextCtrl put it in the dict and done.

```
my_dict = {}
self.sampleTextCtrl = wx.TextCtrl(self, wx.NewId(), "", size = (200,-1))
value = self.sampleTextCtrl
buttonId = wx.NewId()
self.buttonF = wx.Button(self, buttonId, label = "Select File")

mydict[buttonId] = value
```

Done

Comment: To give the solution to your own question please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using a dictionary is certainly one way to go. Another way would be to use Python's lambda statement to pass the paired text control to the function that opens the file dialog. By doing it this way, you can use the text control instance to set the value from the dialog. Here's some code that demonstrates the concept:

```
import wx

########################################################################
class MyPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        self.mainsizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        add_btn = wx.Button(self, label="Add")
        add_btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onAdd)
        self.mainsizer.Add(add_btn, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def onAdd(self, event):
        """"""
        gen_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        txt = wx.TextCtrl(self, size=(600, -1))
        gen_sizer.Add(txt, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

        browse_btn = wx.Button(self, label='Browse')
        browse_evt = lambda evt, ctrl=txt: self.onBrowse(evt, ctrl)
        browse_btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, browse_evt)
        gen_sizer.Add(browse_btn, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        self.mainsizer.Prepend(gen_sizer, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        self.mainsizer.Layout()


    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def onBrowse(self, event, ctrl):
        """"""
        wildcard = "Python source (*.py)|*.py|" \
            "All files (*.*)|*.*"
        dlg = wx.FileDialog(self, message="Choose a file",
                            defaultFile="", wildcard=wildcard,
                            style=wx.OPEN | wx.CHANGE_DIR)
        if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            path = dlg.GetPath()
            ctrl.SetValue(path)
        dlg.Destroy()


########################################################################
class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title='Dynamic file browser',
                          size=(1024,768))
        panel = MyPanel(self)
        self.Show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MainFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

You might also want to check out the following links for more information:

- http://wiki.wxpython.org/Passing%20Arguments%20to%20Callbacks
- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/07/19/the-python-lambda/