# wxPython - Using filedialog to update a textctrl

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, wxwidgets

I am trying to create a basic dialog to edit a settings file. I have some list of necessary files

```
options = ["dog", "cat", "chicken"]
```

I then have a column with the option names in StaticText and a column of TextCtrl to input the file location. Next to each TextCtrl is a "Select File" button.

How can I have each button select a file and then update the TextCtrl with the location? At the moment, I iterate through the options list to generate the text and buttons. I know if I were to define everything by hand, I could have a handler unique to each button which updates the the corresponding TextCtrl, but I feel like there is a better when. I would like it to be modifiable so I can just add an option to the options list, and another row of options is added.

Currently I am binding each button to self.OnSelect, but I'm not sure how to use that to update the correct TextCtrl. To reiterate I know how to use FileDialog, I am just having troubles tying each button to its corresponding TextCtrl.

```
selectBtn = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_FILE, label="Select File")
selectBtn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnSelect)
```

Should I have a unique ID instead of using wx.ID_FILE?

I am relatively new to GUI desgin so any help is appreciated. Even if you think what I'm doing may be ugly and something else would be better, please let me know

Comment: Well I posted a little too soon. A very similar problem was posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32512376/wxpython-how-to-put-a-text-in-textctrl-with-a-button-inserted-by-add-button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer was derived from here: [wxPython how to put a text in TextCtrl with a button inserted by "Add" Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32512376/wxpython-how-to-put-a-text-in-textctrl-with-a-button-inserted-by-add-button)

By using lambda to create anonymous functions, the solution is quite simple. You can have a handler, like:

```
def OnSelect(self, event, ctrl):
    name, path = selectFile() #gets name and path using FileDialog
    ctrl.SetValue(path)
```

The buttons can be bound like

```
selectBtn = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_FILE, label="Select File")
selectEvent = lambda event, ctrl=txt: self.OnSelect(event, ctrl)
selectBtn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, selectEvent)
```

Works like a charm.